# Fit h1 div Height to Font Size

Tags: html, css

I edited the font size of my h1 tag, but it looks like the height of the div doesn't automatically fit it:

[image]

I tried manually setting the height, but then the div just extends below instead of encasing the text:

[image]

Is there any way to make the div fit to the font size?

Here's my css:

```
h1 {
    background-color: red;/* TEST */

    font-family: Lobster;
    font-size: 66px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 26px;
}
```

Comment: line height 26 on a font size 66 and asking why it won't fit? C'mon ...you had only two things to change and play with in your CSS...

Comment: Maybe he don't understand relation between Line-height and font-size, also the questionable is concept of line height. Don't be hard on him :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
h1{
    background-color: red;/* TEST */

    font-family: Lobster;
    font-size: 66px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;/*Change is here, don't put px at the end*/
}
```

See if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `line-height` and `font-size` to the same value:

```
font-size: 66px;
line-height: 66px;
```

Comment: Using `line-height: 66px` will mean that you'll always need to change the `line-height` value according to the `font-size`.By setting `line-height` to 1 though,  you are basically saying the same thing but in a dynamic way, since 1 will be multiplied (based on docs) to the font-size and the result will be the same.

`font-size: 66px; line-height: 1;`